# проблемы с работой aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

У меня есть функция

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE chatid = {message.chat.id}")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    if row == None:
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        buttons = [
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="⏭Пропустить⏭", callback_data="notref")
        ]
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Users(chatid, ref) VALUES ({message.chat.id}, '0')")
        conn.commit()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Добро Пожаловать {message.chat.first_name}\nКто тебя пригласил:\n(Пример ввода: @andrey22)", reply_markup=keyboard)
        @dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
        async def ref(message: types.Message):
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Users SET ref = '{message.text}' WHERE chatid = {message.chat.id}")
            conn.commit()
            await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(f'photo/1.gif', 'rb'), caption=f'<b>Введите ссылку:</b>', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
            pass
```

Вторая функция

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def ref(message: types.Message):
    if code in message.text:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        buttons = [
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ1 - {price[0]} руб", callback_data="f1"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ2 - {price[1]} руб", callback_data="f2"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ3 - {price[2]} руб", callback_data="f3"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ4 - {price[3]} руб", callback_data="f4")
        ]
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(f'photo/func.gif', 'rb'), caption=f"Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)
        pass
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ссылка неверного формата!")
        pass
```

Я раньше писал на телеботе, и вот тут возникла проблема. Когда пользователь прожимает старт, и вводит реферала, срабатывает вторая функция а первая просто перестает работу. Как решить эту проблему? есть что то типо next step?

Comment: используйте FSM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Штош. Вот.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class InputRef(StatesGroup):
    input_ref = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE chatid = {message.chat.id}")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    # слудет использовать is при сравнение с None, False, True
    if row is None:
        # Шо это за бред? Вы делаете ReplyKeyboardMarkup а внутрь пихаете инлайн кнопку
        # markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Users(chatid, ref) VALUES ({message.chat.id}, '0')")
        conn.commit()
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        markup.add("⏭Пропустить⏭")
        # нет смысла юзать bot.send_message если вы отправляете в этот же чат, юзайте answer()
        await message.answer(
            f"Добро Пожаловать {message.chat.first_name}\n"
            f"Кто тебя пригласил:\n"
            f"(Пример ввода: @andrey22)",
            reply_markup=markup)
        # запускаем стейт
        await InputRef.input_ref.set()


# хендлер который ловит Пропуск ввода реферала
@dp.message_handler(state=InputRef.input_ref, text="⏭Пропустить⏭")
async def ref_skip(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # закрываем стейт и все данные в нем
    await state.finish()


# хендлер который ловит ввод реф пользователя
@dp.message_handler(state=InputRef.input_ref)
async def ref_input(message: types.Message):
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Users SET ref = '{message.text}' WHERE chatid = {message.chat.id}")
    conn.commit()
    if not message.text.startswith("@"):
        await message.answer("Вы ввели неверную ссылку на юзера.\nПопробуйте снова")
        return

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ1 - {price[0]} руб", callback_data="f1"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ2 - {price[1]} руб", callback_data="f2"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ3 - {price[2]} руб", callback_data="f3"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"функ4 - {price[3]} руб", callback_data="f4")
    )
    await message.answer_photo(
        photo=open(f'photo/func.gif', 'rb'),
        caption=f"Выберите действие:",
        reply_markup=markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```